# Dynamically show fields based on user on standard record page for FSL object eg. Service Appointment

Tags: fsl, dynamic-forms

How can we dynamically show fields based on user on standard record page for FSL object eg. Service Appointment.
I am having a requirement where I need to dynamically show fields and section based on user without creating record type. As there is no option for dynamic form in that object as well.

What can be the best possible way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `related record` component. You can create quick actions with desired fields and then connect these to related record components. You can use conditional visibility so that users will only see the relevant Related Record component.

[image: Lightning app builder edit page]

[image]
See related [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273539/selecting-fields-on-a-related-record-component-of-lightning-page) on Selecting Fields on a related record component

P.S. I got this suggestion from a team member.